# Neither the property "X" nor one of the methods "X()", "getX()"/"isX()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class

Tags: symfony

I am working on making a form based on an old one which is almost identical.
I copied pasted it and just made few changes in names.
I get this error and I do not know where and how to define the "properties" and "methods" as asked by the error message.
[image: Property nor one of the methods non existent]

I can post one part of the code if you tell me which one.
I was wondering if the problem has to do in part because of big capitals I changed into small capital by inadvertently.

Here is form.html.twig of DataDFu2

```
<h4>1. Date of assessment</h4>
        <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
            <div style='white-space: nowrap'>
              <div class='col-xs-5'>
                <div class='col-xs-2'>{{ form_widget(form.dfu2.fu2Date, { 'id': 'fu2Date1', 'attr':{'style':'width:100px'}})}}</div>
              </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Martin Fasani asked me in the comments to upload Entity\DataDFu2. It is too long. But he is right, there is no property named dfu2 neither the getters, but in the class DataDFu2, there are these functions among others:
By the way, I changed dfu2 in form.html.tiwg to DFu2).

```
public function setFu2Weight($fu2Weight)
    {
        $this->fu2Weight = $fu2Weight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fu2Weight
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFu2Weight()
    {
        return $this->fu2Weight;
    }
```

Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Do you have any Model attached to your form ?

Comment: Can you show `DataLiveBundle:DataDFu2:form.html.twig` around line 122 please.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question and and put that part of the code.

Comment: If you don't copy the entity/form this question is useless. It seems the entity does not have a property named "dfu2" or the getters are not there...

Comment: Martin Fasani, I uploaded a piece of code from the entity/form